# Miniprofiler: Send metrics to influxDB

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, miniprofiler

Is there a way to send miniprofiler metrics to influxDB? Or hook to it so you can capture the metrics and then forward them to another DB.

Answer (score 0):

This does not exist today, but there are some things towards it. For example, MiniProfiler v4 ships with a `MultiStorageProvider`. This allows you to store the same profiler to multiple places like a primary store (e.g. in-memory for a bit) *and somewhere else* (like a metrics store).

MiniProfiler v4 has a convention of providers ([see the current list in the repo](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/src)). If we added a metrics store for Influx DB all of the other bits are there to mirror the data and send, etc. If someone is interested in adding this I'd be happy to look at a PR for it! I don't have Influx setup to test nor does our current build server support it for automated testing...so we'd need some community expertise to help here :)